# Role Based Access Control for Asmx web service methods

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, authorization, asmx

I have an asmx web service runs with .net 4.5 and it is old project. I aware of there is no Authorize filter for asmx.How to build a structure like that

```
[MyAuthorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[WebMethod]
public string DisableUser(string UserId)
{ 
  ...
}

[MyAuthorize(Roles = "Admin,HRemployee")]
[WebMethod]
public string GetUserInfo(string UserId)
{ 
  ...
}
```

I want to append [MyAuthorize... etc. attribute to all method in webservis descripted above. I don't prefer to write code
User.IsInRole("HREmploye") inside each function. Can I add custom attribute to apply role-based permission to all method

Comment: Place the asmx file in a folder, and add a web config to that folder with the role(s) that are allowed. So, how one secures a regular aspx page, or a asmx one? The same approach can be used.